# Retrieve tableWidget row from button in corresponding row

Tags: c++, qt

I have a tableWidget, for which I dynamically create rows using

```
ui.tableWidget->insertRow(0);
QTableWidgetItem *newItemText = new QTableWidgetItem("bla", 0);
QPushButton *goButton = new QPushButton("Go", ui.tableWidget);
connect(goButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_pushButtonGo_clicked_custom() ));
ui.tableWidget->setItem(0, 0, newItemText);
ui.tableWidget->setCellWidget(0, 1, goButton);
```

In each row I have a cell "Go" and a cell containing a Button. These buttons all connect to the slot on_pushButtonGo_clicked_custom.

Now within on_pushButtonGo_clicked_custom, I need to retrieve the corresponding row, in which the button was clicked. How can I do that?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QSignalMapper](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html) allows associate string or integer with the original signalling object. It means that you can associate every `goButton` with according row. [Example in documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html#details) looks related with your question.

You need modify you code something like this:

```
...
#include <QSignalMapper>
...

QSignalMapper * signalMapper = new QSignalMapper (this);
ui.tableWidget->insertRow(0);
QTableWidgetItem *newItemText = new QTableWidgetItem("bla", 0);
QPushButton *goButton = new QPushButton("Go", ui.tableWidget);
signalMapper->setMapping (goButton, 0); // where 0 is row number.
connect(goButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
// You need rewrite slot for passing number of row.
connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(const int)), this, SLOT(on_pushButtonGo_clicked_custom(const int)));
ui.tableWidget->setItem(0, 0, newItemText);
ui.tableWidget->setCellWidget(0, 1, goButton);
```

Number of row will be available through argument of `on_pushButtonGo_clicked_custom(const int)` slot:

```
...
void MainWidget::on_pushButtonGo_clicked_custom(const int rowNumber)
{
    qDebug () << "Row number is: " << rowNumber;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gluttton
I modified the slot function to "on_pushButtonGo_clicked_custom(const int)".
How do I retrieve the mapped integer (0) in here?
Shouldn't there be an argument name after const int?

Comment: @user2926577, yes you can get number of row using parameter of slot. I've updated my answer.